# CMT JTA, but "no transaction is in progress"

Tags: java, spring, jpa, transactions, jta

I'm able to call `entityManager.merge(obj)`, but not `entityManager.flush()`.

I am getting "no transaction in progress".

My application context has:

```
<jee:jndi-lookup jndi-name="${persistenceEMFJndiServerName}"
    id="entityManagerFactory" expected-type="javax.persistence.EntityManagerFactory" />


<bean id="entityManager"
    class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.support.SharedEntityManagerBean">
    <property name="entityManagerFactory" ref="entityManagerFactory" />
</bean>

<bean id="transactionManager" class="org.springframework.transaction.jta.JtaTransactionManager" >
</bean>
```

My persistence unit says transaction-type="JTA"

and I'm loading it via

```
@PersistenceContext 
private EntityManager entityManager;
```

I've tried a few things, like:
`entityManager.joinTransaction()`,
`entityManager.getTransaction().begin()/.end()`,
`@Resource UserTransaction` with `BEAN` transaction management, but it says I cant, with JTA.  There's just no transaction going on.

My method has

```
@Transactional  
@TransactionAttribute(TransactionAttributeType.REQUIRED)
```

and it's an EJB, so I'm getting pretty annoyed.  CMT JTA is supposed to do transactions all by itself.

Comment: If it is an EJB then why use spring? If you use Spring you need to add `<tx:annotation-driven />` to tell spring to do something with `@Transactional`.

Comment: Add bean code to the question as it looks like you are mixing EJB with Spring. If you are using EJB, then you shouldn't try to inject entityManager via Spring. And what server are you using?

Comment: I have <tx:annotation-driven /> already.  I'm mixing Spring (v4.0.6) and EJB3, and using JBoss eap 6.3.  I can get the entityManager via JNDI instead, but that doesn't help with the transaction.

Comment: @djb If you have `@Stateless` in your class (still missing from your question), then remove `@Transactional`, and remove all transaction related entries from your Spring configuration, as it is not needed. Also ensure that your Datasource is set to JTA, as by default in JBoss it is not.

Comment: I do have `@Stateless`, and now I've removed all @Transactional s, and my datasource is transaction-type="JTA" and has jta-data-source defined.  But no.  I agree it should work.  Perhaps the issue is that the code is within a processor of a camel route.  But all parts of the chain are `@Stateless` up to that code.

Comment: Now I get "No transactional EntityManager available"

Comment: Ok I've removed all trace of EJB in my code.  "no transaction is in progress"

Answer (score 0):

Turns out it wasn't a JPA/JBoss/etc. issue.  It was because my thread ran in a camel context.

It took me a day of searching to [find out](http://archive.apachecon.com/eu2012/presentations/08-Thursday/L2R-Camel_MQ/aceu-2012-apache-camel-in-action_common-problems_solutions-and-best-practices.pdf):

Important
: One transaction is associated with a single thread of execution!
– If you use “seda”, “vm”, “jms” or any other protocol in your sub route which will process the exchange in an different thread, this execution will not be part of this transaction context!

FYI:
"asynchronous transactions in Camel 3.0.0"

I had my entityManager.merge/flush code in a thread.  Hence, no transaction.  Got rid of thread, and now it works fine.